# Filtering related Nodes and Links D3.js V5

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to filter related Links and Nodes by a values in Links?

For example filtering nodes and links where filter_columns = 12

```
 "links": [
    {
        "source": "13600",
        "target": "4112",
        "filter_column": 12
    },
    {
        "source": "4112",
        "target": "7423",
        "filter_column": 12
    },
    {
        "source": "7423",
        "target": "3042",
        "filter_column": 12
    },
    {
        "source": "3042",
        "target": "965",
        "filter_column": 12
    },
    {
        "source": "13600",
        "target": "965",
        "filter_column": 12
    },
    {
        "source": "11290",
        "target": "8953",
        "filter_column": 1
    },
    {
        "source": "8953",
        "target": "972",
        "filter_column": 1
    },
    {
        "source": "972",
        "target": "2376",
        "filter_column": 1
    },
    {
        "source": "11290",
        "target": "2376",
        "filter_column": 1
    }
],
```

Full Json: https://jsfiddle.net/zqsnacbg/

I am ussing this code to create the graph:

https://bl.ocks.org/mapio/53fed7d84cd1812d6a6639ed7aa83868

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS directly. Say your data is in `data` - to filter, use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter).

```
var filteredData = data.filter(d => d.filter_column === 12)
```